# Add worksheet in already existing data in excel

Tags: r, excel

I have a data frame saved in a variable called ecoftp

now I have two others two variables called Failed and Successful

I want to create another worksheet in excel and add the other two variables Failed and Successful to the ecoftp

basically, add worksheet in already data frame in excel

I want something like this picture below

[image]

Comment: You can check the `openxlsx` package.

Comment: i don't understand how it works can you help with the code

Answer (score 0):

```
library(openxlsx)

old_excel <- loadWorkbook(PATH TO OLD EXCEL FILE)

addWorksheet(wb = old_excel, sheet = "Successful")
writeData(wb = old_excel, sheet = "Successful", x = Successful)

addWorksheet(wb = old_excel, sheet = "Failed")
writeData(wb = old_excel, sheet = "Failed", x = Failed)

saveWorkbook(old_excel, PATH AND NAME TO NEW EXCEL FILE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Note: this code assumes that in your old Excel file there aren't yet sheets "Successful" or "Failed". If the file already contains such sheets you need to remove those first (openxlsx package has a function for that).

Comment: wb<-createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = c("Errank_autosettlement",`Successful Transactions`,`Failed Transactions`))
see the error i encountered.
Warning messages:
1: In if (tolower(sheetName) %in% tolower(wb$sheet_names)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Please see my code. I'm adding one worksheet at a time whereas you are trying to add several ones.